# Pole calculation -180 not +180 phase

Tags: feedback

Gain in feedback system is defined by:
\${V_{out} } /{V_{in}} = A / (1+Af) \$

We have a pole when \$|Af|=1\$ and \$\angle Af =-180\$

Any complex number can be expressed as \$z=r(cos \theta +j\sin \theta)\$

But when \$\theta=180 or -180 , cos \theta=-1\$ in both cases and sine is zero.

So why in the definition, it says the phase is \$-180\$ deg not positive \$180\$, to me both yield the same result.

Comment: -180 **is** +180, it's only convention, or custom, which you'd use. Unless you're unwrapping phase that is, which you're not here.

Comment: Your use of the term pole is incorrect, I believe you mean't 'oscillator' not 'pole'

Comment: Because the phase angle at a slightly lower frequency is -179deg. If you plot phase against frequency and use 180 instead of -180 at the next increment, your graph will have a huge discontinuity as it jumps from -179 to +180.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big reason for preferring -180 is: feedback control for **causal systems**. In causal systems, only delays are possible which correspond to a minus-signed phase shift.

In non-causal systems, which can respond to "future" data, it is perfectly sensible to be able to have positive-signed phase shifts. This is possible whenever data is not time dependent. E.g. You have an image and your feedback control system is a filter operating on that image.

Comment: Also possible when future data is **predictable**, e.g. from a table of stored typical behaviour.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert by any stretch, but is that kind of a system still causal, or is that more of an exercise of turning a cause system in to a non-causal system?

Comment: With predictions, you are leaving causality as predictions can be wrong. It's still useful sometimes to analyze the case when the prediction is right.

Comment: Oh sure! I can see the applicability of making causal systems non-causal. I just wasn't sure how they were classified. Thank you for clearing that up.